# PHP Date Array to user friendly string

Tags: php, cakephp

Hello i have one array as below.

```
$testArray = array
    (
        '12 AM - 01 AM',
        '01 AM - 02 AM',
        '02 AM - 03 AM',
        '03 AM - 04 AM',
        '04 AM - 05 AM',
        '06 AM - 07 AM',
        '07 AM - 08 AM',
        '08 AM - 09 AM',
        '09 AM - 10 AM',
        '10 AM - 11 AM',
        '11 AM - 12 PM',
        '12 PM - 01 PM',
        '01 PM - 03 PM',
        '03 PM - 04 PM'
    );
```

Now all i want to show a string as

```
 12 AM -05 AM,06 AM - 04 PM
```

Please little hint or help would save my time.
Thanx...

Comment: So you want to show strings that are not in your array?

Comment: @user: Please clarify your question, that makes no sense at all.

Comment: whats the realtion between 12 AM  and 05 AM of 12 AM -05 AM  and similarly for 06 AM - 04 PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Using string functions:

$temp = explode('-',$testArray[0]);
        $start_str = $temp[0];
        $comma = '';

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($testArray); $i++) {

        $temp = explode('-',$testArray[$i]);

        $prev_start = $temp[0];
        $prev_end = $temp[1];
        $prev_endtime = (integer) $prev_end;

        $temp = explode('-',$testArray[$i+1]);
        $start = $temp[0];
        $end = $temp[1];

        $starttime = (integer) $start;
        if($prev_endtime != $starttime){
            $op .= " $comma $start_str - $prev_end";
             $comma = ',';
            $start_str = $start;
        }
}
echo $op;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some working sample code which outputs:

```
12 AM - 05 AM, 06 AM - 04 PM
```

You can use this, or edit it to work however you want:

```
<?php

    $testArray = array
    (
        '12 AM - 01 AM',
        '01 AM - 02 AM',
        '02 AM - 03 AM',
        '03 AM - 04 AM',
        '04 AM - 05 AM',
        '06 AM - 07 AM',
        '07 AM - 08 AM',
        '08 AM - 09 AM',
        '09 AM - 10 AM',
        '10 AM - 11 AM',
        '11 AM - 12 PM',
        '12 PM - 01 PM',
        '01 PM - 03 PM',
        '03 PM - 04 PM'
    );

$now = time();
foreach($testArray as $trange){
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/(\d+ (?:A|P)M) - (\d+ (?:A|P)M)/', $trange, $matches);
    if(!isset($start)){
        $start = $matches[1][0];
        $end = $matches[2][0];
    }else if(strtotime($end, $now) === strtotime($matches[1][0], $now))
        $end = $matches[2][0];
    else{ // End time not equal to previous start time
        echo $start , ' - ' , $end, ', '; 
        $start = $matches[1][0];
        $end = $matches[2][0];
    }
}

echo $start , ' - ' , $end;

?>
```